# Problem: Could not convert string to float: 'Travel_Frequently'

Tags: python, string

I have a data set of employee. I am trying to apply K nearest neighbor. Dataset hast 34 attributes and 1029 rows. Among 34 attributes, 7 attributes are object type. I am getting this error "Could not convert string to float: 'Travel_Frequently' ." How can i solve it. Sometimes, its also showing "list is out of index". How can i solve it?

````
import random
import operator
import math

def getdata(filename):
    with open(filename,'rb') as f:
        reader = unicodecsv.reader(f)
        return list(reader)

with open('employee.csv','rb') as f:
    reader = unicodecsv.reader(f)
    taposh = list(reader)

len(taposh)

def shuffle(taposh):
 random.shuffle(taposh)
 train_data = taposh[:int(0.7*11)]
 test_data = taposh[int(0.7*11):]
 return train_data, test_data

def euclideanDist(x, xi):
 d = 0.0
 for i in range(len(x)-1):
    d += pow((float(x[i])-float(xi[i])),2)
 d = math.sqrt(d)
 return d

def knn_predict(test_data, train_data, k_value):
    for i in test_data:
        eu_Distance =[]
        knn = []
        good = 0
        bad = 0
        for j in train_data:
            eu_dist = euclideanDist(i, j)
            eu_Distance.append((j[5], eu_dist))
            eu_Distance.sort(key = operator.itemgetter(1))
            knn = eu_Distance[:k_value]
            for k in knn:
                if k[0] =='g':
                    good += 1
                else:
                    bad +=1
        if good > bad:
            i.append('g')
        elif good < bad:
            i.append('b')
        else:
            i.append('NaN')

def accuracy(test_data):
    correct = 0
    for i in test_data:
        if i[1] == i[2]:
            correct += 1

    accuracy = float(correct)/len(test_data) *100  
    return accuracy

dataset = getdata('employee.csv')  
train_dataset, test_dataset = shuffle(dataset) 
K = 3                                         
knn_predict(test_dataset, train_dataset, K)   
print (test_dataset)
print ("Accuracy : ",accuracy(test_dataset))```
````

Comment: Add the full traceback for this (those?) errors. It contains more useful information than you know.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that in employee.csv you've got strings in some rows that you try to handle as floats. Search for Travel_Frequently in your csv to find the exact location for the error in the data.

In general it is a good programming practice to verify the type of the data you're reading to make sure it is indeed a float.

Comment: Hi, thanks for commenting. Under "Business Travel" attribute column, Travel_Frequently is there. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: You should change your logic to treat this column as a string, not as a float.